# HLF v1.0 - does the peer support PKCS11 in the BCCSP config?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

as the Admin I would avoid to store private keys as regular files located in subdirs of "mspConfigPath" since it can be a security problem for some use cases. It'd be great to keep all sensitive crypto material inside HSM.

According to the documentation of the Fabric CA server it is possible to configure server to use a software version of PKCS11 called softhsm.

Q: is it supported by the peer to use PKCS11 in BCCSP section of core.yaml config file?

as it is done in BCCSP section of Fabric CA server configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - there is a BCCSP section in core.yaml - https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L228